# Longest illusion in Dota2

Tags: dota-2

I have somewhat idea that illusions from runes last for around a minute. But apart from that which heroes/items illusions live the longest?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Illusions spawned from a rune last 75 seconds, which is the longest.

Outside of that, Morphling's level 3 ultimate is the longest at a 60 second duration.

Comment: The illusion of winning the game lasts about 45 min. At least for me

Comment: ohh. the closest I had in mind was CK phantasms. the reason I asked this question was recently I saw that If you have a gem, then your illusions also get true sight. Hence it would be safer to send your illusions to deward instead of you going and risking the gem. What do you think of this?

Comment: @Wandang nice :D. For me its till my friends listen to me.

Comment: @MandeepJain it could work indeed, but if it's late in the game you might want to use your illusions to teamfight instead. If it's too early (assuming you have a gem) your illusions do not deal a lot of damage and might not be able to take down wards fast enough